# Execution failed for task app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForDebug

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-play-services

when i try to run my app i get these errors:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForDebug'.
```

> java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.

```
This is my Gradle file
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    debug {
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
    }
}
}
repositories {
mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.8.00'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.8.00'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.8.00'
compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.3.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.8.00'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

can any one say why am i getting this error?

it shows some jar files are duplicate ,but i dont know which dependency to remove.

Comment: you have `com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.8.00`, `com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.8.00`, `com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.8.00`. So, I think there is no need of `com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.8.00`

Comment: You'll also want to switch to 9.8.0 (with a single 0), which is the most recent release.

Comment: Do you really want `minifyEnabled true` for your debug build?  If so, you should also specify `proguardFiles`.  Try disabling `minifyEnabled` to see if you get better results.

Answer (score 17):

add the below to your ProGuard rules

```
-ignorewarnings
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer,worked for me. Removing **minifyEnabled true** doesn't solve the problem,it just removes the usage of proguard.

Comment: Agreed this fixed it for me, however its worth taking a look at warnings and fix as needed, instead of simply ignoring them.

Answer (score 0):

Add following to the debug section:

```
proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
```

If you are setting minifyEnabled to true, you need to have proguardFiles defined. If you don't need minifyEnabled, just set it to false. Then you don't need to add proguardFiles.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    debug {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro', 'proguard.cfg'
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. So I checked the the third parties and update the third parties Gradle versions in my app level Gradle. It worked for me. Actual one the third party version was deprecated. Which was causing the issue. Hope it will help someone.

Answer (score 0):

adding `useProguard true` worked for me

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score -1):

Remove

```
debug {
        minifyEnabled true
    }
```

This worked for me

Comment: This just disable Proguard, Not Solving the Problem

Answer (score -1):

1. Remove     `minifyEnabled true`
   from `debug` if you are getting error while compiling the app. As this time its running `debug` part.

   ```
   buildTypes {
     debug {
       minifyEnabled true// (<--Remove)
       proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
               'proguard-rules.pro'
     }
   }
   ```
2. Remove     `minifyEnabled true`
   from release if you are getting error while creating final releasing api.

   ```
   buildTypes {
     release {
       minifyEnabled true// (<--Remove)
       proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
     }
   }
   ```

Comment: Removing **minifyEnabled true** or switching it to **false** doesn't solve the main problem, it just removes the usage of proguard.