# Getting error :app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForDebug while enable proguard

Tags: android, android-proguard

I am trying to use proguard in my application. Here is my build.gradle file look like :

```
  release {
        debuggable true
        minifyEnabled true
       // shrinkResources true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }

    debug {
        debuggable true
        minifyEnabled true
       // shrinkResources true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
```

While i try to run the project its showing the following error:

```
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForDebug'.
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:103)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:73)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:59)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:59)
at ..... (I excluded rest of the error trace)
```

I didn't find any expected answer for this error type. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40258804/execution-failed-for-task-apptransformclassesandresourceswithproguardfordebug) similar question asked but all the answer are pointing out that i need to remove `minifyEnabled true`. But i cannot do this as i need to use proguard.

So whats the possible reason for this error and how can i overcome this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can add below lines in your proguard and check. I hope it will work for you.

```
 -ignorewarnings 

 -keep class * { 

     public private *; 
  }
```

Comment: I have added this but no success, still showing the same error. Please let me know if i need to provide you any other information in order to get help from you. Thanks for answer